# How does min_df work?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've got a document classification problem with only 2 classes and my training dataset matrix size, after the CountVectorizer becomes (40845 X 218904). I'd like to know how I'll be able to remove the least frequent 4 words/features when min_df must be a float between 0 and 1. I even got good accuracy and F1 results by modifying the min_df value to 4; however I couldn't explain what's exactly happening. I'm using python sklearn (scikit-learn) package on an 6GB machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all in the [doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), but anyway:

- if min_df is a float between 0 and 1, it is interpreted as a proportion: All words with a frequency lower that that proportion of the document will be ignored
- if min_df is a int, it is interpreted as a count: All words appearing less often than this count are ignored

Comment: Actually the docs aren't fully correct: `min_df` and `max_df` look at the *document* frequency, not the term frequency, i.e. the number of documents a term occurs in. I'll push a patch immediately.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. min_df puts a cap on words appeared in the least  number of document, or appeared the least in the whole corpus.